# Issues converting json data to a dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas

I am using the [pushshift api](https://github.com/pushshift/api/blob/master/README.md#pushshift-reddit-api-documentation) to gather posts in a Reddit subreddit. But some of the returned data from the request is throwing an error which is:

```
"None of [Index(['author', 'id', 'title', 'score', 'created_utc', 'permalink',\n       'num_comments'],\n      dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"
```

I understand that it means that some of the columns have spaces in them but the thing is that I am running this request over 112 different days and 94 times it is successful. So I am struggling to figure out how to fix it when the request ideally should return the same format of data every time as the only thing I am changing is the range of days for `before` and `after`.

I cannot fit the entire json object which is returned but you can check it for yourself by running this:

```
import requests
from pprint import pprint

link = "https://api.pushshift.io/reddit/search/submission/?size=100&before=111d&after=112d&sort_type=num_comments&sort=desc&subreddit=wallstreetbets"
sample = requests.get(link).json()
pprint(sample)
```

#### Full code:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests 

for i in reversed(range(2, 113)):
  after_ = i
  before_ = i - 1
  link = f"https://api.pushshift.io/reddit/search/submission/?size=100&before={before_}d&after={after_}d&sort_type=num_comments&sort=desc&subreddit=wallstreetbets"
  path = f"/content/drive/MyDrive/UsersWSB/Posts/days_after_{after_}.csv"
  try:
    sample = requests.get(link).json()
    df = pd.DataFrame(sample['data'])
    # I only need these columns from the entire df
    df = df[['author', 'id', 'title', 'score', 'created_utc', 'permalink', 'num_comments']]
    df.to_csv(path)
  except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Answer (score 0):

In full code you are not testing for expected conditions

1. response is an error `status_code!=200`
2. response JSON did return data....

```
import pandas as pd
import requests 

if True:
    df = pd.DataFrame()

link = "https://api.pushshift.io/reddit/search/submission/"
for i in reversed(range(2, 113)):
    after_ = i
    before_ = i - 1
    params = {"size":100,"before":f"{before_}d","after":f"{after_}d","sort_type":"num_comments","sort":"desc","subreddit":"wallstreetbets"}

    # DL is very slow,  only DL if haven't done so already
    if len(df)==0 or len(df.loc[df.before.eq(before_) & df.after.eq(after_)])==0:
        req = requests.get(link, params=params)
        # check request succeeded and it returned some data...
        if req.status_code == 200 and "data" in req.json().keys() and len(req.json()["data"])>0:
            df = pd.concat([df, pd.json_normalize(req.json()['data']).loc[:,['author', 'id', 'title', 'score', 'created_utc', 'permalink', 'num_comments']].assign(before=before_,after=after_)])
        else:
            print(f"{req.status_code} {params} {'error' if req.status_code!=200 else req.json()}" )

print(f"***DONE*** downloaded: {len(df)}")
```

Comment: I tried this with the full code but the error is still there.

Comment: updated - you need to test for expected conditions,  http response codes and a request did respond with data